# Trying to extract text using Selenium in Python gives only whitespaces

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Text positioning image:

[image: Text positioning image]

I write a code using python with selenium and XPath to extract text from a website as shown in the Text positioning image above. However, it only returns white spaces.

```
street = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Div1"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody[8]/tr/td/text()').text
print(street)
```

I've also tried

```
street = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Div1"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody[8]/tr/td').text
print(street)
```

Comment: Could you please add link to page or something to help us know that you located this element correctly?

Comment: street = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Div1"]/div[1]/div/table/tbody[8]/tr/td').text
road = street.split(' ')
print(road)

try this?

Comment: Can you share that HTML with little bit more content in text format